# Finding the disparity to depth matrix using Matlab

Tags: matlab, computer-vision

I have the Rotation matrix and the translation vector between the 2 cameras .Is there a way to find out the 4 X 4 disparity-to-depth mapping matrix using Matlab ?
I used [this link](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/bouguetj/calib_doc/index.html#parameters) for finding the R and T parameter values between the two cameras.

Comment: Please clarify your question. One talks about disparity when the pair of images is already rectified (i.e. the epipolar lines are coincident). It seems that in your case they are not, and you find extrinsic and intrinsic calibration matrices. Knowing them, there are closed-form formulas for 3D coordinates of the point given by projections to both images, and it is easy to compute the distance to the point from each of the image planes (this is called triangulation). Do you need something like this?

Comment: Thanks for the input.I do use rectified images.My overall aim is to produce 3 d points given image and its disparity map.For this I wa calculating the R and T matrices between the cameras.What I am looking for is basically matlab equivalent of this function in opencv http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#reprojectimageto3d

Answer (score 0):

You can always compile OpenCv and use it in matlab as external DLL.